# Spark Dynamic passing of id after creating dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I had nearly 20 id's nothing but clients. My problem is when creating dataframe on top of data(reading)

```
val id = 88888
val df = inputDataDF.filter($"id" === id).join(....)
```

I know dataframes are immutable but is there any way to pass id dynamically. Since so that for Ist id i will cache all the dataframes so that for second id performance will be improved...

Comment: How you get 20 ids ? you can try command line args.

Comment: presently I am passing it one by one from conf so each time I pass the id it is recreating dataframe

Comment: what do you want to achieve now? what is the existing solution with 20 ids?

Comment: I am iterating with for loop providing id = "1,2,3" for dataframes `for(i <- 0 until id.split(",").length){ ***** all the logic(dataframes) }..` Is there any way that reading all the data frames ones and caching them and executing results for each id... my logic reads all the dataframes for each id

Comment: I am wondering how to handle data associated for each I'd since I had several join condition based on id and corresponding IDs accounts .. after joining I will save the data partitionby respective I'd ..If there is any small example that will be very usefull